# Showing a matrix in $\text{GL}_3(\mathbb{Z}[x])$ doesn't exist.

Tags: abstract-algebra, matrices

For a ring $R$, we denote $\text{GL}_3(R)$ as the group of $3\times 3$ matrices with entires in $R$ and determinant in the units $R^{\times}$.

I want to show that no matrix in $\text{GL}_3(\mathbb{Z}[x])$ has first row $(6\quad 2x\quad 3x)$.

As an example in $\text{GL}_3(\mathbb{Z})$, we see that a matrix with first row $(6\quad 10\quad 15)$ is 
$$\begin{bmatrix}
6 & 10 & 15\\
-1 & 1 & 0\\
0 & 1 & 1
\end{bmatrix}$$
as $\gcd(6,10,15)=1$ so by Bézout's identity there exists integers $a,b,c$ such that $$6a+10b+15c=1.$$

Can I extend this similar argument to $\text{GL}_3(\mathbb{Z}[x])$?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**HINT**

1) What are the units of $\mathbb{Z}[x]$ ??

2) Show that if there was such a matrix then its constant term should be divided by $6$

3) This is a contradiction

Comment: The units in $\mathbb{Z}[x]$ are the units of $\mathbb{Z}$, namely $\pm 1$. If there was such a matrix, $$\begin{bmatrix}
6 & 2x & 3x\\
a & b & c\\
d & e & f
\end{bmatrix}$$ the determinant formula would give $$6(bf-ec)-x(2(af-dc)+3(ae-db))=1$$

Comment: you missed a $x$, it is $3x(ae-db)$

Comment: I factored the $x$ so I have 6(integer)-x(integer)=1

Comment: So since these two polynomials are equal you have $6|1$

Answer (score 2):

For a unital commutative ring $R$ and $M\in GL_3(R)$ then
$$\{(1,0,0) M v, v\in R^3\}$$ is an ideal of $R$ and taking $v=M^{-1} \pmatrix{1\\0\\0}$ we get that this ideal is $R$.

Your ideal is $(6,2x,3x)$ which is smaller than $\Bbb{Z}[x]$ because it is contained in the maximal ideal $(2,x)$.